# Compare last element of a row to the rest of a row in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a dataframe in pandas which holds numeric data.

E.g:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,3,2], 'col2': [3, 4,1,2],'col3':[1,3,4,1}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

What I want to do is compare the elements in the third column with the other elements in their respective row in terms of something each element in row n < last element of row n return true / false or 1 / 0.

```
#Desired Output:
resDf = {'col1':[False,True,True,False],'col2':[False,False,True,False]}
```

What I have done so far is use `apply` like this:

```
resultBoolDf = df.iloc[:,:-1].apply(lambda x: np.where(x < df.col3,1,0),axis = 0)
```

So this does not seem to work since I assume that the comparison is not iterating correctly.
Could somebody give me a tip on how to solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.lt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lt.html) for compare with last column selected by position:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1].lt(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0)
#if want specify last column by label
#df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1].lt(df.col3, axis=0)
print (df1)
    col1   col2
0  False  False
1   True  False
2   True   True
3  False  False
```

Last if need `0,1` convert to integers by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1].lt(df.iloc[:, -1], axis=0).astype(int)
#if want specify last column by label
#df1 = df.iloc[:,:-1].lt(df.col3, axis=0).astype(int)
print (df1)
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     0
2     1     1
3     0     0
```

Your solution with [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is possible use with `DataFrame` constructor:

```
arr = np.where(df.iloc[:,:-1].lt(df.col3, axis=0),1,0)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(arr, index=df.index, columns = df.columns[:-1])
print (df1)
   col1  col2
0     0     0
1     1     0
2     1     1
3     0     0
```